# pyVISA Error When Reading Data Within a Function

Tags: python, pyvisa

I am writing a simple python program using pyVISA to build an array of values and save it to a .csv file. The program works perfectly if I use a while loop to continuously acquire data, but when I try to place the .read() command in a function, I get a 'The given session or object reference is invalid' error. This error is only present when I run the function.

The functioning code segement:

```
while True:
    my_instrument.write('MEASure:CURRent:DC?')
    value = my_instrument.read()
    voltage.append(value.strip('\n'))
    print(voltage)
```

However this returns the error:

```
def whatever():
    my_instrument.write('MEASure:CURRent:DC?')
    value = my_instrument.read()
    voltage.append(value.strip('\n'))
    print(voltage)
```

I have written much more complex programs involving tkinter and matplotlib's animation library, in which I defined many utility functions involving reads and writes with no issues, but for some reason this simple program is not behaving. I have to assume I'm missing something obvious. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where do you call it from?

Comment: I've tried simply calling it immediately after defining it and simply defining the function without calling it. Both result in the same error.